# What is the correct implementation to refresh a token with MSAL in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a desktop program that requires user permissions to access a Sharepoint list. I have implemented the necessary structure to authenticate a user and retrieve its token with acquire_token_silent() method. As uploading into a list may take some time, I want to make sure the token is refreshed. I can not make the user login again because that would stop the uploading process due to the redirect to the login form. After doing some research I have implemented the next code:

Before uploading data refresh token and check:

```
token = _get_token_from_cache(MYSCOPE)
        if not token:
            return redirect(login page)
```

During the data upload:

```
token = _get_token_from_cache(MYSCOPE) 
if not token: 
   token = methodB(MYSCOPE)
   if not token: 
      return redirect(login page)
```

The function methodB is:

```
def methodB(scope):
    cache = _load_cache() 
    a = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)
    accounts = cca.get_accounts()
    if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user
        result = a.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=accounts[0])
    if not result:
        result = app.acquire_token_by_xxx(scope)
        _save_cache(cache)
        return result
```

As in the beginning, I already check if the user is loged I would like to know if there is any way to avoid the login redirect during the uploading process. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we already have some accounts that the end user already used to sign in before,  `acquire_token_silent` will find a token in cache for this account and it will automatically handle the token refresh for you.

But if there is no suitable token in the cache, you need to send a request to AAD to obtain a token.

You could use [Username Password Flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication) to *avoid the login redirect*, only this one fits your situation although it is not recommended. There is a [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/username_password_sample.py) using Python.

```
accounts = app.get_accounts(username=config["username"])
if accounts:
    logging.info("Account(s) exists in cache, probably with token too. Let's try.")
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=accounts[0])

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
        config["username"], config["password"], scopes=config["scope"])
```

The configuration file would look like this:

```
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>",
    "client_id": "your_client_id",
    "username": "your_username@your_tenant.com",
    "password": "This is a sample only. You better NOT persist your password.",
    "scope": ["User.ReadBasic.All"],
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
}
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is config exactly, thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Danielakaws. I edit my reply with configuration.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am sorry to ask again but I think I am not abble to retrive the user's password because my app is going to be used by multiple users loged with their work account. I am using msal and session. Thanks again.

Comment: You could try to use [`acquire_token_for_client`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/confidential_client_secret_sample.py#L61) which is based on application and you could use it without user.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has a chosen answer. I would like to provide some more relevant information for your consideration.

The OP started by mentioning the app in question is a "desktop program", but the code snippet was derived from MSAL Python's web app sample. For a desktop program, you would be better of starting from [MSAL's interactive sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/1.15.0/sample/interactive_sample.py) which also takes care of refreshing your tokens.

That way, you won't need to use the username password method, which is not recommended anyway.